# WordPress - Inline style shortcode for background-image doesn't render

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode in a style attribute:

```
<div style="background-image: url("[my-shortcode id="1"]");"></div>
```

The Problem is that the shortcode will be not rendered.

I found out that in the function `safecss_filter_attr()` (in w-includes/kses.php on Line: 1688) the regex filters the `(` and returns an empty string.

This particular case isn't working because of a security restriction.

Is there another way to render shortcodes in div attributes?

Comment: Something like :  `<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo do_shortcode('[my-shortcode id="1"]'); ?>);"></div>`

Comment: Did also not work :(

Answer (score 0):

did you try to `echo` the output of your short code on the page to see what it returns to make sure it works?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my-shortcode id="1"]'); ?>
```

You could also try saving it in a variable. The nospan is necessary because WordPress outputs it inside of a `<span>` by default:

```
<?php
  $shortcode_url = do_shortcode('[my-shortcode id="1" nospan="true"]');
?>
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $shortcode_url; ?>);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that,

```
function my_shortcode_function() { 
     $i = '<p>Hello World!</p>';
    return $i;
} 
add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function');


<div style="background-image:url('<?php echo do_shortcode('[my-shortcode]'); ?>');"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to put the shortcode in the post content (visual composer html element).

So i need to render it with the whole html code:

```
<div style="background-image: url("[acf field='my_field' post_id='123']");"></div>
```